# Compile Error: Undeclared member that is actually declared

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, datamember

I have created a class that works as it should except for three supplemental member functions. In all of the other public member functions I refer to a private data member and I have no trouble accessing the data I need; however, with these three particular functions Dev C++ compiler responds with: "'matrix' undeclared, first use this function(matrix is the private data member.) I have attached a sample function that works fine in my client program as well as the three problem children.

```
bool boolMatrix::get(int row, int col) const{
    assert (row < ROW_SIZE  && col < COL_SIZE);     

    if(matrix[row][col]){
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}


int rowCount(int row){
    int trueCount = 0;
    assert(row < ROW_SIZE);
    for (int colCount = 0; colCount < COL_SIZE; colCount++){
        if(matrix[row][colCount]){
            trueCount++;
        }
    }

    return trueCount;
}



int colCount(int col){
    int trueCount = 0;
    assert(col < COL_SIZE);

    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < ROW_SIZE; rowCount++){
        if(matrix[rowCount][col]){
            trueCount++;
        }
    }

    return trueCount;
}



int totalCount(){
    int trueCount = 0;
    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < ROW_SIZE; rowCount++){ 
        for (int colCount = 0; colCount < COL_SIZE; colCount++){
            if (matrix[rowCount][colCount]){
                trueCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    return trueCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "boolMatrix::"  to totalCount() and colCount(int col)

Comment: You just need a cup of coffee or beer(if allowed):)